# get Response header on Success by ajax actionlink in mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

There is ajax `actionlink` on my page.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Pending", "ApproveRequest", "Admin", new { Id = request.Id }, new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "divItemAdd",OnSuccess="Successfun" })
```

My `ApproveRequest` return some data and also add a response header.

```
public ActionResult ApproveRequest(int Id)
        {
            using (ServiceRequestsApiController serviceRequestsApiController = new ServiceRequestsApiController())
            {
                var getMsg = serviceRequestsApiController.ApproveRequest(Id);
                if (getMsg == "1")
                    getMsg = "Request Approved";
                Response.AddHeader("X-Msg",getMsg);
                return ServiceRequest();
            }
        }
```

in jquery function, I have written this

```
function Successfun(xhr, status)
    {
        var x = xhr.getResponseHeader("X-Msg")
        bootbox.alert(x);
    }
```

but it's showing `xhr.getResponseHeader` not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first argument passed to your success handler will be the data that your action method returns, and the jQuery xhr wrapper will be the *third* argument. So this should work:

```
function Successfun(data, status, xhr)
{
    var x = xhr.getResponseHeader("X-Msg");
    bootbox.alert(x);
}
```

Comment: no . still getting same error in cosole `xhr.getResponseHeader("X-Msg");`

Comment: Oops, sorry - I think I got that order wrong. I've edited my answer - xhr is the third argument, not the second